# alternative to mutex lock/unlock when accessing class data

Tags: c++, mutex, openmp

I am trying to make `my_class` thread-safe like so.

```
class my_class
{
  const std::vector<double>& 
  get_data() const
  { //lock so that cannot get_data() while setting data
    lock l(m_mutex);
    return m_data;
  }

  void
  run()
  {
    vector<double> tmp;
    //some calculations on tmp.
    {  //lock so that cannot get_data() while setting m_data
      lock l(m_mutex);  
      m_data = tmp;  //set the data
    }
  }

private:
  std::vector<double> m_data;
  mutex m_mutex;
  my_class(); //non-copyable
}
```

`run()` and `get_data()` may be called by different `openmp` threads and so I introduce a lock. 
(Since am using openmp, `m_mutex` and `lock` are RAII wrappers around `omp_init_lock();` etc. commands).

However, the lock on `get_data ()` is expensive to create and destroy (The most expensive operation when I profile my code - I call `get_data()` a lot).

**Is is possible to reorganise my_class to remove the lock in `get_data()`?**  Or is this lock the unavoidable cost of parallelising the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First step would be to look into read-write locks: this way multiple readers will not block each other.

The next step would be using lock-free or wait-free operations.  There are plenty of resources online describing them better than I would be able to.  Just one note: lock-free approaches deal with atomic (interlocked) operations, which means the data size needs to be small.  If you go this route, you'll be atomically replacing a pointer to your vector, not the whole vector.  This means your class will get a bit more complex and will deal with some pointers and memory management.

Comment: I don't think openmp supports read-write locks, unfortunately.  I hadn't heared of lock-free and wait free operations.  I will look them up now, thanks!

Comment: Yep, lock-free what I wanted I think.  For the next person, i found the following presentation useful: www.cs.cmu.edu/~410-s05/lectures/L31_LockFree.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It may be cheaper to use a critical section around get_data/run functions, you will not incur additional setup/teardown overhead (as the critical section is statically initialized), but  this would also synchronize other instances of the class.